# Creating a xml sitemap from an url with c#

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap

I'm trying to create a utility that will create a xml sitemap using c#.  I'm able to point it at a local folder and produce results that display in a browser, but am having trouble when I point it at a website.  Any tips or hints would be appreciated!  I'm rather new to c#.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        //String sDir = @"WWW.WEBSITE.COM";<---I'd like to index a site rather than a file.
        String sDir = @"FOLDER_LOCATION";
        String siteMap = @"FOLDER_LOCATION\sitemapworking.xml";//Where I'd like to save the sitemap
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();


        String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        String[] alldirects = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        sb.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<urlset>");
        sb.AppendLine("<url>\n\t<loc>" + sDir + "</loc>\n</url>");

        foreach (string s in alldirects)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<url>\n\t<loc>" + s + "</loc>\n</url>");
        }

        foreach (string s in allfiles)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(s);
            sb.AppendLine("<url>\n\t<loc>" + s + "</loc>\n\t<lastmod> " + file.LastWriteTime + "</lastmod>\n</url>");
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</urlset>");
        File.WriteAllText(siteMap, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: The web is not a file system.

Comment: I don't think you are fully grasping the complexity of what you are trying to achieve.  You'll have to write a web crawler which is basically an HTTP client which reads the given URL, searches for internal links and then recursively proceeds to crawl each link.  You'll have to think about breadth-first v.s depth-first crawling, canonical URLs, possible honeytraps (URLs which produce the same content over and over causing the crawler to get stuck etc), recursion limits etc etc.  This is not a trivial task!

Comment: I now realize this.  I'm just starting to deal with the interwebs.  Part of my shortcoming is not acknowledging the difference between what I've done and the web as TyCobb pointed out.  I really appreciate your assistance!